# Mysql randomly restarts with different args?

Tags: mysql

I'm facing a rather strange problem and I'm not sure how to make sense of it.
It looks like the mysqld process is being started with different args by something other than systemd after the mysql systemd service is already running. This causes the mysql server to go down and the new process to become unresponsive.

When started through systemd:
`/usr/sbin/mysqld`

When started by ?
`mysqld --user=mysql --init-file=/var/lib/mysql-files/tmp.Ld6xyAe3qb --socket=/tmp/tmp.obBArlPCj2/mysqld.sock --pid-file=/tmp/tmp.obBArlPCj2/mysqld.pid`

**It is unclear why mysql is being restarted, by who, and where the new arguments are coming from.**

`/var/lib/mysql-files/tmp.Ld6xyAe3qb` (which is the init-file supplied above) contains the following text:

```
USE mysql;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH 'auth_socket';
SHUTDOWN;
```

The only thing I can see in the logs is:

```
2020-08-08T06:57:31.123013Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4).
... [group replication, InnoDB, normal logs] ...
2020-08-08T06:57:49.954754Z 8 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user boot. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4).
```

The first log occurs randomly; there is nothing before it that indicates a memory or any other kind of error (that I can see). The second shutdown seems to come from the init-file. However, the more confusing aspect is that there is no user `boot` on the system or in mysql.

The only service using mysql is OpenStack Keystone for the purpose of Swift object-store and no other OpenStack services.

As far as I can tell, there is no other cron or systemd service that references mysql but I'm not positive on that test. The command was:
`systemctl list-units --all --no-legend | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n1 systemctl cat 2>/dev/null | grep mysql`
which gives:

```
After=postgresql.service mysql.service keystone.service rabbitmq-server.service ntp.service network-online.target local-fs.target remote-fs.target 
# /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service
User=mysql
Group=mysql
PIDFile=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld
RuntimeDirectory=mysqld
```

The first line is from `/lib/systemd/system/cinder-volume.service`, which needs to be removed but I do not believe to be related to this issue, as the problem occurs on servers that never had cinder installed

This problem occurs on 4 servers set up for group replication.

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

```
# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

```
# cat /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf 
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html
# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram
[mysqld]
log-error-verbosity = 5
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
# pid-file  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
# socket    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
# port      = 3306
# datadir   = /var/lib/mysql
# If MySQL is running as a replication slave, this should be
# changed. Ref https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmpdir
# tmpdir        = /tmp
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 16M
# max_allowed_packet    = 64M
# thread_stack      = 256K
# thread_cache_size       = -1
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
# max_connections        = 151
# table_open_cache       = 4000
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
#
# Log all queries
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/query.log
# general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
# slow_query_log        = 1
# slow_query_log_file   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
# long_query_time = 2
# log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
# server-id     = 1
# log_bin           = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
# binlog_expire_logs_seconds    = 2592000
max_binlog_size   = 100M
# binlog_do_db      = include_database_name
# binlog_ignore_db  = include_database_name
# disable non innodb storage engines for group replication
# https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication-configuring-instances.html
disabled_storage_engines="MyISAM,BLACKHOLE,FEDERATED,ARCHIVE,MEMORY"
# use native password auth
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
# replication framework settings
server_id = 1
gtid_mode = ON
enforce_gtid_consistency = ON
log_bin = binlog
log_slave_updates = ON
binlog_format = ROW
master_info_repository = TABLE
relay_log_info_repository = TABLE
binlog_checksum = NONE
# group replication settings
plugin_load_add = 'group_replication.so'
plugin-load-add = 'mysql_clone.so'
group_replication_group_name = "xxx"
group_replication_start_on_boot = on
group_replication_local_address = "xxx:33061"
group_replication_ip_whitelist="xxx"
group_replication_group_seeds = "xxx:33061"
group_replication_bootstrap_group = off
group_replication_enforce_update_everywhere_checks = off
group_replication_single_primary_mode = off
## tls
# required encrypted remote connections
# require_secure_transport = ON
tls_version=TLSv1.3
ssl_ca = "/etc/mysql/certs/eons.dev.pem"
ssl_cert = "/etc/mysql/certs/skyrim-mysql.pem"
ssl_key = "/etc/mysql/certs/skyrim-mysql.key"
ssl_cipher = "DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA"
##ssl_crl = "crl-server-revoked.crl"
##ssl_crlpath = "/.../crl_directory"
mysqlx_ssl_ca = "/etc/mysql/certs/eons.dev.pem"
mysqlx_ssl_cert = "/etc/mysql/certs/skyrim-mysql.pem"
mysqlx_ssl_key = "/etc/mysql/certs/skyrim-mysql.key"
mysqlx_ssl_cipher = "DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA"
# group replication tls
group_replication_ssl_mode = REQUIRED
group_replication_recovery_use_ssl = on
group_replication_recovery_ssl_ca = "/etc/mysql/certs/eons.dev.pem"
group_replication_recovery_ssl_cert = "/etc/mysql/certs/skyrim-mysql.pem"
group_replication_recovery_ssl_key = "/etc/mysql/certs/skyrim-mysql.key"
group_replication_recovery_ssl_cipher = "DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA"
```